# Font used in pharmacy software for numbers

Tags: font-identification

I simply want to know the name of the font used for the numbers in this image.

[image]

Update: I have already used many of the font identifiers but none gave me result so I decided to ask here. I really heavily searched the net even Google with image search but I couldn't find it.

It is from software a I use in pharmacy I work at.

Comment: Hi user1531557, we have some [requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and edit your question to include that information.

Comment: It's hard to tell which font this is exactly just from a couple of numbers and some punctuations. I've done some searching though, and find that  "UW ttyp0" comes pretty close. Also, search google for things like "monospace bitmap font" or "programming fonts". You'll notice there are quite a lot of examples of similar looking fonts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all ur help. Appreciate it so much and I will begin search now but if you guys don't mind I will be back if I was lost in a black hole. Max

Comment: Is there a reason you need the specific font used? If you search for "pixel font" or "bitmap font" you will get a lot of similar results. The problem with identifying bitmap fonts like this at such small sizes is that each size will look very different (i.e 6px will look very different to 10px)

Comment: I need this exact font for system I do so yes the exact was needed but thanks god I found it by the help of martie comment. Thanks guys

Comment: @user1531557 you can answer your own question if you solved it on your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it and it's called [Fixedsys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixedsys).

[image: Fixedsys]